# com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, objectify

The android application has a dependency: `com.googlecode.objectify`
The following error is thrown while building the project:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/homecomp/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.googlecode.objectify/objectify/5.1.16/148ca59a5f89b394eb998ce1894d222c7e11131d/objectify-5.1.16.jar
```

Here is the complete build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.homecomp.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.16'
}
```

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWN2c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be very surprised if the Google App Engine SDK (which Objectify depends on) works on Android. If it did, it would certainly require the Remote API.

You might try Objectify6, which uses a newer Google SDK and REST-based API and is more likely to work on Android. You should check.

That said... directly accessing your datastore from a mobile app? Sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: You are right. I don't need to have this lib on the app.